# Not able to see the list of Databases in Server Navigation Panel while using Azure Data Studio

Tags: database, azure, directory, ssms, azure-data-studio

Please see the picture below: -

[image: Database Folder not found]

I am not able to find the `Database` Folder which consists of all the database objects like `Tables`, `Views` etc. Instead I am directly getting all the Database Objects without the Database Folder in my `Azure Data Studio` application.

I am trying to look for the following folder (Sample image given below): -

[image: Sample Image of what I want]

Please guide on how to make the `Database` folder visible in the `Server Navigation Panel` of `Azure Data Studio` application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the view without the Database folder when you connect to a specific database vs just the server (leaving the setting as < Default >).

[image]